# JS: Problem with shopping button not bringing selected items to the checkout page

Tags: javascript, html

For an e-commerce site using JS, I have built a functional shopping cart using the localStorage and HTML using the classes, id, and spans. My problem is getting the items chosen to reflect on the cart page. I have written the code but it doesn't seem to respond to what's listed. I have attached my JS and Html below:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
const cartIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-cart-arrow-down')
const wholeCartWindow = document.querySelector('.whole-cart-window')
wholeCartWindow.inWindow = 0
const addToCartBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart-btn')
addToCartBtns.forEach( (btn)=> {
  btn.addEventListener('click', addItemFunction)
} )

function addItemFunction(e){ 
  const id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id")
  const img = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.src
  const name = e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent
  const desc = e.target.parentElement.children[0].textContent
  let price = e.target.parentElement.children[1].textContent
  price = price.replace("Price: $", '')
  const item = new CartItem(name, desc, img, price)
  LocalCart.addItemToLocalCart(id, item)
}


cartIcon.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
if(wholeCartWindow.classList.contains('hide'))
wholeCartWindow.classList.remove('hide')
})

cartIcon.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
  //if(wholeCartWindow.classList.contains('hide'))
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(wholeCartWindow.inWindow===0) {
      wholeCartWindow.classList.add('hide')
    }
  } , 500)
  
  })

wholeCartWindow.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
  wholeCartWindow.inWindow = 1
})

wholeCartWindow.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
  wholeCartWindow.inWindow = 0
  wholeCartWindow.classList.add('hide')
})

function updateCartUI(){
  const cartWrapper = document.querySelector('.cart-wrapper')
  cartWrapper.innerHTML = ""
  const items = LocalCart.getLocalCartItems('cartItems')
  if(items === null) return
  let count = 0
  let total = 0
  for(const [key, value] of items.entries()) {
      const cartItem = document.createElement('div')
      cartItem.classList.add('.cart-item')
      let price = value.price*value.quantity
      price = Math.round(price*100)/100
      count+=1 
      total += price
      total = price = Math.round(price*100)/100 + 5.31
      cartItem.innerHTML = 
      `
      <img src= ${img}>
                      <div class="details">
                          <h3>${name}</h3>
                          <p>${desc}
                              <span class="quantity">Quantity: ${quantity}</span>
                              <span class="price">Price: $${price}</span>
                          </p>
                      </div>
        <div class="cancel"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-xmark"></i></div>
      `

     cartItem.lastElementChild.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      LocalCart.removeItemFromCart(key)
     })
     cartWrapper.append(cartItem)
  }

  if(count > 0) {
    cartIcon.classList.add('non-empty')
    let root = document.querySelector(':root')
    root.style.setProperty('--after-content', `"${count}"`)
    const subtotal = document.querySelector('.subtotal')
    subtotal.innerHTML = `Subtotal: $${total}`
  }
  else
  cartIcon.classList.remove('non-empty')
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{updateCartUI()})
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="shop-section">
             <div class="card-wrapper">
                    <!--Item 1-->
                        <div data-id="1" class="card-item">
                            <img src="images/Shop/IMG-5288.jpg">
                            <div class="details">
                                <h3>Black Sweatsuit</h3>
                                <p>Kingdom
                                    <a class="price">Price: $85.00</a>
                                    <span class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!--Item 2-->
                    <div data-id="2" class="card-item">
                        <img src="images/Shop/IMG-5290.jpg">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h3>Grey Sweatsuit</h3>
                            <p>Kingdom
                                <a class="price">Price: $85.00</a>
                                <span class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <!--Item 3-->
                    <div data-id="3" class="card-item">
                        <img src="images/Shop/IMG-5292.jpg">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h3>Red Sweatsuit</h3>
                            <p>Kingdom
                                <a class="price">Price: $85.00</a>
                                <span class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <!--Item 4-->
                    <div data-id="4" class="card-item">
                        <img src="images/Shop/IMG-5294.jpg">
                        <div class="details">
                            <h3>Blue Sweatsuit</h3>
                            <p>Kingdom
                                <a class="price">Price: $85.00</a>
                                <span class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: Could you please explain this: `My problem is getting the products to upload to the cart.`

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of the problem so that we don't have to guess.  For example, what steps you follow and the result compared to what you expected. And yes, the "upload to cart" is unclear.

Comment: You're code is missing a lot of necessary elements to run properly. For example: `cartIcon`, `wholeCartWindow`, `cartWrapper` elements, `LocalCart` object... How can someone test it without a complete example?

Comment: that technically isn't upload